# Weird behaviour after deleting/commenting code

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth, servo

I've run into some weird behaviour and looks like I can't find an answer. I've written some simple code to control a servo motor via bluetooth using my phone.

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include "SoftwareSerial.h";

int servoPin = 2;

int bluetoothTx = 11;
int bluetoothRx = 10;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

Servo myservo;
char unChar;
String readString;

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);
    bluetooth.begin(115200);
    delay(100);
    bluetooth.begin(9600);

    myservo.attach(servoPin, 800, 2200);

}

void loop() {

    if (bluetooth.available()) {
        unChar = bluetooth.read();
        Serial.println(unChar);

        if (unChar == 'A') {
            motor();
        }
    }
}

void motor() {
    delay(15);
    while (bluetooth.available()) {
        char c = bluetooth.read();
        readString += c;
    }
    if (readString.length() > 0) {
        Serial.println(readString.toInt());
        myservo.write(readString.toInt());
        readString = "";
    }
}
```

For android, I used the MIT App Inventor to make a basic slider.
[image: app inventor blocks]

I'm using an Arduino Mega 2560, Power HD High-Torque High-Voltage Digital Servo 1218TH and a Bluetooth Mate Silver RN-41.

Everything works fine with the exception of the servo stuttering while dragging the slider on the phone. That is one small problem. The weird behaviour appears when I comment or delete my code in the arduino loop. The servo still stutters on its place when I play with the slider. What causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-adjust the **delay time** after delete comment, it happens because add debug log inside the loop needs time to show up. In other words, that comment inside the loop has an impact on delay time.

Comment: To what delay time are you referring?

Comment: i mean you need to add the delay time inside loop method.